# Дата-время. Как определить, что дата больше, а время меньше?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть стобец типа *DATETIME*. Хранит дату и время в виде `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Можно ли, не разделяя время и дату на отдельные столбцы, делать следующую выборку?

Вывести те строки, где дата больше `2015-09-22`, а время меньше `15:00:00`.

---

Проблема в том, что *mysql* не разрешает использовать два оператора.
Выводится ошибка:

> Operator 'DATE_CLEANING < '2015-09-22' AND DATE_CLEANING > '15:00:00'' requires two operands

Comment: Ваш запрос хорошо бы было увидеть.

Comment: вам действительно требуется ограничение *ansi sql*, или метку [tag:sql] вы добавили по ошибке?

Comment: Если это mysql вот так должно бы работать : `date(DATE_CLEANING < '2015-09-22' and time(DATE_CLEANING > '15:00:00'`

Answer (score 1):

для независимой от даты проверки времени нужно «извлечь» время из *datetime*, например, с помощью функции [`time()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time).

пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70d13/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (d datetime);

insert into t values
   ('2015-09-22 16:00')
  ,('2015-09-22 10:00')
  ,('2015-09-21 16:00')
  ,('2015-09-21 10:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from t
where
  d < '2015-09-22' and
  time(d) > '15:00:00'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70d13/1/0)**:

```
|                           d |
|-----------------------------|
| September, 21 2015 16:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from t
where
  d > '2015-09-22' and
  time(d) < '15:00:00'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70d13/1/1)**:

```
|                           d |
|-----------------------------|
| September, 22 2015 10:00:00 |
```